# A Visitor Observing Shabbath

Tags: halacha, shabbat

If a non-Jew or a non-observant Jew visits an observant Jew for a couple of days, and one of those days is the Shabbath, are they obligated to observe Shabbath if they’re staying with the observant Jew?

Comment: A non-observant Jew is obligated to observe the Shabbat whether or not he visits an observant Jew. A non-Jew is forbidden to full observe the Shabath and should respect his host while in his home, i.e., not desecrate the Shabbat in common areas. What he does in his private room (if any) should be agreed in advance with the host

Comment: A noahide can observe the Shabbat but is not required too like a jew

Comment: @RaulValdezJr. What if they are staying in the home of a Jew on Shabbath?